# Get error in all whereRaw query after update Laravel 9 to 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I get an exception with this error after updating Laravel from 9 to 10:

> [2023-08-16 13:11:00] local.ERROR: [ "status Code:" 0] "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to string" on line   of file
>
> [2023-08-16 13:11:00] local.ERROR: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to string {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to string at /srv/www/site.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php:222)

Every query before updating to version 10 works very well! But after the update to Laravel 10, we get this error! Why? What is the problem?

Comment: could you please provide us with some code examples of queries?

Comment: You probably didn't upgrade per documentation: check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#database-expressions). You have to find every place where raw queries are used in application and make change accordingly.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code generating this error.